# How to install back-end infrastructure on firebox server?

Tags: quickblox

Looking to install the application on the server. Can quickblox be installed on firebox server?

Answer (score 0):

You can contact QuickBlox team regarding Enterprise installations questions http://quickblox.com/enterprise/

it can be doable only with Enterprise plan